# UISearchBar Cancel Button Language

Tags: ios8, uisearchbar, cancel-button

I'm trying to change the language of the ui search bar cancel button title to Chinese. I've tried a few of the solutions mentioned for iOS 7 but can't get them to work. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to localize "cancel" button's title based on different language in iOS System.You can change the CFBundleDevelopmentRegion key in Info.plist.

```
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>zh_CN</string>
```

Or you can select them in Xcode Editor: choose "Localization native development region" = > "China"